# Using Fish + NVM + Sublime results in commands not found

Tags: path, sublime-text-3, fish

I'm using Fish shell/omf, NVM (https://github.com/derekstavis/plugin-nvm), and Sublime Text 3. I'm trying to use a build system to run `nodemon` (which I installed with `npm -g install nodemon`). `nodemon` works fine from within a native Fish shell:

```
~ » nodemon                                                                                                                                                                           15:47:56
  Usage: nodemon [nodemon options] [script.js] [args]

  See "nodemon --help" for more.
```

If I run `which nodemon`, I get:

```
~ » which nodemon                                                                                                                                                                     15:48:05
/Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v7.5.0/bin/nodemon
```

(expected, from what I understand).

**The problem:**

Sublime doesn't seem to recognize the NVM path. Take this build system:

```
{
    "shell": true,
    "cmd": ["nodemon '$file'"],
    "selector":"source.js"
}

/bin/sh: nodemon: command not found
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 127]
[cmd: ["nodemon '/Users/me/Dev/tmp/nodemon-test.js'"]]
[dir: /Users/brandon/Dev/tmp]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin]
```

I see that the path variable for Sublime doesn't have the NVM search path:

```
~ » echo $PATH                                                                                                                                                                        15:48:20
/Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v7.5.0/bin /usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin
```

What's the correct way to fix this to make Sublime's $PATH match Terminal's $PATH? I'd expect it to continue to work even when I switch Node versions with NVM too.

Edit:

Yes, I'm using the [omf](https://superuser.com/questions/905255/how-to-get-fish-shell-and-nvm-both-installed-with-homebrew-to-work-together/1008519) solution for NVM, which works because I can run both `nodemon` and `node` from Terminal directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide an [option](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/reference/build_systems.html#options) for the `path` in your build-file.

PS: I'm assuming you already [set up fish to support nvm](https://superuser.com/questions/905255/how-to-get-fish-shell-and-nvm-both-installed-with-homebrew-to-work-together/1008519)

Comment: Yes to your second point, but as for the path option, that means that each time I change node version I'm going to have to manually update that in the build system right? Unless NVM has some alias somewhere for "current version"?